# BinaryDescriptor in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror, line-segment

My goal is to implement the tutorial as below.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/df/dfa/tutorial_line_descriptor_main.html

I found `BinaryDescriptor` in OpenCV/Python.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/ddd/group__line__descriptor.html

[image: 1]

I tried to use it, but failed.

```
bd = cv.createBinaryDescriptor()
```

But I only show the message:

`AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createBinaryDescriptor'`

Comment: The bit of documentation you highlighted says `cv.line_descriptor.BinaryDescriptor.createBinaryDescriptor()`, not `cv.createBinaryDescriptor()`, but that aside, this functionality is from contrib, so you need to use a build of OpenCV that includes contrib modules (the standard binary releases usually don't).

Comment: Thanks! It is reasonable.
By the way, how can I build contrib modules and build it?

Comment: don't, unless you're absolutely sure that you have to. instead, remove all opencv packages, then `pip install opencv-contrib-python`